# Unable to mount exfat external hardrive in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, mount, disk, exfat

I am trying to mount an external hard drive (exFAT partition) on my machine (CentOS7).

I read that exfat is not natively handled so I installed `exfat-utils` and `fuse-exfat` rpm packages by doing:

```bash
yum install -y http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
yum install exfat-utils fuse-exfat
```

I tried to plug again the hard drive on the USB port of my machine but the hard drive does not show up in the File system.

*edit1* : no new message appear with `dmesg` after external hard drive connection

*edit2* : the hard drive is not damaged/corrupted, a colleague is able to mount it without issue (Ubuntu-22.04)

Do you have any recommendations ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: IIRC Linux kernel 5.4 and later ship a kernel module that can deal with exfat natively. Which kernel are you running (`uname -r` is your friend)?

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller, thank you for your help.
Here is the kernel release I have `3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64`

Comment: oh that is slightly ancient. Yeah, you'll need that FUSE exfat implementation …

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have no choice on the OS, it is a machine handled by the IT service of my institution.


I installed both `exfat-utils` and `fuse-exfat` using yum package manager, and reboot the machine afterwards, but still do not see the hard drive.

Comment: does the drive appear in `lsblk`?

Comment: no, it does not appear on `lsblk` (the HD is not corrupted, my colleague is able to mount it, his machine is on Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: ah well that means having the right file system drivers won't help. It doesn't appear as raw block device, so it can't even be attempted to be worked with :( run `dmesg |tail -n50` before and after you've connected your external drive and post the difference (the new messages) as part of your question, please!

Comment: I have no access to the machine today, I'll give an update asap. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, unfortunately nothing new appears in `dmesg` message after external HD connection :/

Comment: that means the device isn't even detected as connected. So, this is a hardware issue, it seems!

Comment: hmm too bad, thank you for your help anyway @MarcusMüller

Comment: Is the usb-storage kernel module loaded (lsmod | grep usb-storage)?  Maybe your IT crew disabled usb-storage for paranoid security reasons?  Or many other possible not-hardware-broken reasons.  It could be a hardware issue, of course, but often it's not.